# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select a column for editing in Atom editor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

### Scenario

When editing a file in [Atom Editor](http://atom.io) how do I select multiple lines where the same edit needs to be performed?

For example:

```
this.name  = name;
this.age   = age;
this.sound = sound;
```

needs to be transformed into:

```
that.name  = name;
that.age   = age;
that.sound = sound;
```

Imagine there are *many* of these lines, but we do *not* want to use a find-and-replace because it will change more than we need.

### Question - Is there a *Keyboard Shortcut* for Column Selection?

Is there a sequence of ***keyboard shortcuts*** (*preferably Mac*) which we can use to:

- a) select the initial word
- b) select the "column" (that word on several lines)

then apply the change to several lines at once (*in bulk*)

I know how to do this in SublimeText:
http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/editing/editing.html#column-selection but have tried many different key combinations without any luck in Atom and googling has proved fruitless...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

## Keyboard

You can enable column selection mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑/↓</kbd>. This will allow you to extend the cursor to multiple rows. Once you have selected all rows, release the keys, and use the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to remove the text you want to replace. Once you're done, press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to release the cursors.

> Note: You *will* have to disable the *Mission Control* (*key bindings*) in OS X to use this key combo.

### How to Disable Mission Control (*conflicting*) Key Bindings (*Mac*)

To do this open System Preferences > Mission Control

[image]

Locate the key bindings for **Mission Control** and **Applications windows**:

[image: mission-control-key-bindings]

Disable the key bindings for these two:

[image]

More details [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/column-text-selection/1731).

## Mouse

If you install the [Sublime Style Column Selection](https://atom.io/packages/Sublime-Style-Column-Selection) package, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse to select the columns in question.

More details [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/vertical-text-selection/466).

Comment: Thanks @nwinkler! I didn't think to disable mission control key bindings. have updated your answer with in-line instructions+screenshots for others. thanks again!

Comment: This does not seem to work on Windows. The answer from Vineel Kumar Reddy Kovvuri seems to work though.

Ctrl-D works for this example but is doesn't really mark columns, it seems to mark the next occurence of the selected text ("this" in the question).

Comment: A fantastic answer. Cheers folks!

Answer (score 14):

Here is a plugin for Atom, just hold alt and be happy. 
[sublime-style-column-selection](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection)

Answer (score 13):

With the cursor somewhere on the first "this", do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (OS X: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) three times. Then type "that".

Another option is to select the rows you want to edit. Then select "Split into Lines" from the "selection" menu. Then hit the <kbd>home</kbd>-key and start editing away in multi-cursor mode.

Comment: Thanks for this! 
It was the only thing that worked for me on Windows. Ctrl-D can also expand an already made selection downwards.

Answer (score 10):

For me on Atom 1.7.4 it worked by adding below lines to my /Users/***username***/.atom/keymap.cson. Ofcourse I am using alt-shift-down as shortcuts.

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'alt-shift-down': 'editor:add-selection-below'
```

Update: I could not configure both alt+shift+down and alt+shift+up at the same time. For now I am okay with alt+shift+down

Comment: I had no problem configuring alt+shift+up and +down together. Simply add a third line with content:  'alt-shift-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, follow the following steps:

1. Press ctrl + alt together and use up/down arrow keys to expand the height of your now vertical cursor
2. Now use shift to select the columns to be deleted
3. press delete key to remove selected columns
4. click anywhere on document (without pressing ctrl/alt keys) to bring cursor back to normal 1 column height

Answer (score 0):

I came by this thread, and the feature I was personally looking for was the [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all of the following potential solutions:

1. [sublime-style-column-selection](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection)
2. [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor)
3. [multi-cursor-plus](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor-plus)
4. Adding the following text to */Users/$(whoami)/.atom/leymap.cson*

> ```
> 'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
>   'alt-down': 'editor:add-selection-below'
>   'alt-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
> ```

The last solution is the one that worked best without interfering with any of my other normal workflows.